# flexslider callback after for slideshow not animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, flexslider

i have an event that i want to hide after the slideshow is complete not the animation.

that's my css for the item i want to show and hide

```
.myitem{  font-size: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -21%;
  left: 36px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 11px 26px;}
```

and that's the callback i use

```
  $('#slider').flexslider({
    controlNav: false,
      animation: 'slide',
    animationLoop: true,
      slideshow:true,
    sync: "#carousel",
      useCCS: false,
      easing: 'easeOutBounce',
      slideshowSpeed:2500,

    before: function(){
          $(".myitem").animate({top:"5%"});
      },
          after: function(){
          $(".myitem").animate({top:"-21%"});
      }
  });
```

with 'before' it shows from top and that's good, and with 'after' it hides but after the animation and i want it to hide after each slideshow complete.

Comment: when slideshow ends, i mean one slide ends not all the slides

Comment: this I do not understand. If you mean "after each slide", your code should work. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if flexslider is capable to give you the number of actual slide (or the index, where 0 is the 1st), but you need to count the elements before, pass them as variable to the slide function and you could do like this (6 elements in this example, index 0 to 5)

```
before: function(){
    if (el.is(':eq(0)')) $(".myitem").animate({top:"5%"});
},
after: function(){
    if (el.is(':eq(5)')) $(".myitem").animate({top:"-21%"});
}
```

Comment: where el is the actual visible element, and :eq(5) should be the total number of elements -1 like :eq('+(total-1)+').